# Grey ed out Salesforce standard page

Tags: visualforce

I am displaying a vf page with in a salesforce standard page. That Vf page is showing a small div as a pop-up with a button. Is it possible to grey out the entire window, including the standard page till the user clicks on the button? Using the below css code it is only graying out the embedded VF page and not the complete window.

.popupBackground {
    opacity:0.8;
    background-color:#ccc;
    position:fixed;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    top:0px;
    left:0px;
    z-index:1000;
}

Thanks

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about using JavaScript to create modal popups.

Answer (score 1):

You need a helper companion to bridge the gap between domains. See my [answer on this site](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/21862/custom-button-on-standard-page-layout/21983#21983) for the HTML5 technique for doing this. You may run into complications, though, because you'll have to figure a way to move the iframe above the div in that case, or it will block the entire page, including the content you're trying to expose.